# How select all columns count of all tables by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Today I have this query that returns all rows from all tables. But now I want to add a new column that would be the number of records in the last year. Most tables have a column called "DateInsert".

I have this:

```
SELECT
   SCHEMA_NAME(t.[schema_id]) AS [SCHEMA],
   OBJECT_NAME(p.[object_id]) AS [NOME_TABELA],
   SUM(p.[rows]) AS [ROW_COUNT]

FROM [sys].[partitions] p
INNER JOIN [sys].[tables](NOLOCK) t ON p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
WHERE p.[index_id] < 2
GROUP BY p.[object_id]
    ,t.[schema_id]
ORDER BY [ROW_COUNT] desc
```

How do i add a new column counting rows from the last year only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, each table has DateInsert column. You can try using Dynamic SQL to prepare the count for each table from last year in one temporary table and then you can Join that temp table with your final query.

Something like this

***Please note that, if any of your table dont have DateInsert Column, this query will fail. In order to look at list of tables, you can prepare the dynamic SQL for those tables only***

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- Preparing Dynamic SQL
SELECT @SQLQuery = STUFF(
                            (SELECT CONCAT('UNION SELECT ''', name ,''' AS [TableName], COUNT(1) AS [NoOfRowsFromLastYear] FROM ['
                                         , name
                                         , '] WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE YEAR(DateInsert) = (YEAR(GETDATE())-1)') 
                            FROM [sys].[tables]
                            --WHERE name in ('TableName')
                            FOR XML PATH(''))
                            , 1, LEN('UNION '), ''
                    )
SELECT @SQLQuery = CONCAT('SELECT * INTO ##TableDetail FROM (', @SQLQuery, ') DataSet')

-- Check for table, if available, drop it
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TableDetail') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##TableDetail;

-- Execute prepared query
EXECUTE sp_executesql  @SQLQuery

-- Final Query with [ROW_COUNT_FROM_LAST_YEAR]
SELECT
   SCHEMA_NAME(t.[schema_id]) AS [SCHEMA],
   OBJECT_NAME(p.[object_id]) AS [NOME_TABELA],
   SUM(p.[rows]) AS [ROW_COUNT],
   td.NoOfRowsFromLastYear AS [ROW_COUNT_FROM_LAST_YEAR]

FROM [sys].[partitions] p
INNER JOIN [sys].[tables](NOLOCK) t ON p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
INNER JOIN ##TableDetail td ON td.[TableName] = t.name
WHERE p.[index_id] < 2
GROUP BY p.[object_id]
    ,t.[schema_id]
    ,td.NoOfRowsFromLastYear
ORDER BY [ROW_COUNT] desc
```